# html parsing in java raising exceptions

Tags: java, parsing

I got this in the console when i tried to parse from wikipedia

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: usage: supply url to fetch
at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.isTrue(Validate.java:45)
at org.jsoup.examples.HtmlToPlainText.main(HtmlToPlainText.java:26)
```

this is my java code:

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://wikipedia.com/").get();
 Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
 String news = newsHeadlines.toString();
 system.out.println(news);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you're not actually executing your code, but the Jsoup-provided example code.  (If this wasn't the case, we shouldn't expect to see `org.jsoup.examples.HtmlToPlainText.main` in the stack trace.)

Ensure that you're actually running your own code, rather than the example - which is expecting a URL to be provided on the command line (where as, yours is currently hard-coded).

Comment: i wanted to learn  it... it said ull get whats inside a tag by the elements line ???

Comment: @RoyceRaju - again, the problem is, you're not even making it into *your* program, but an example ("HtmlToPlainText") - which is almost certainly not what you want.  Either use the built-in example, and provide it the argument its requiring on the command-line - or get your command-line, IDE, etc., to run the Java code that you provided in your question.

Comment: ya i got it.thanks.. now running fine.when i ran it as a java application and gave the default package as the example ..thanks